# How to add data to a custom ArrayList using three lists?

Tags: java, android, list, arraylist

I have three `String` `Lists` , I want to use them to populate an `ArrayList` of `ActorData` (POJO class) type, How to properly get this done?

**Data examples**

**actor names**

```
actornames = {
0 = "name1",
1 = "name2"
}
```

**actor characters**

```
actorcharacters = {
0 = "character1",
1 = "character2"
}
```

**actor photo file paths**

```
actorphotoFILEpaths = {
0 = "filepath1",
1 = "filepath2"
}
```

My problem is using the following method in `onCreate` of the `activity class` all three list are collected , i.e. the resulting `actors` list is like this:

```
actors = [
0 = {
     name = "name1",
     character = null,
     photofilepath = null
    },
1 = {
     name = "name2",
     character = null,
     photofilepath = null
    },
2 = {
     name = null,
     character = "character1",
     photofilepath = null
    },
3 = {
     name = null,
     character = "character2",
     photofilepath = null
    },
4 = {
     name = null,
     character = null,
     photofilepath = "photofilepath1"
    },
5 = {
     name = null,
     character = null,
     photofilepath = "photofilepath2"
    }
]
```

**But I want the output to be like this**

```
actors = [
0 = {name = "name1",
     character = "character1",
     photofilepath = "photofilepath1"
    },
1 = {name = "name2",
     character = "character2",
     photofilepath = "photofilepath2"
    }
]
```

**Activity**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    rest of the code ......

    List<String> actornames = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> actorcharacters = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> actorphotoFILEpaths = new ArrayList<>();
    List<ActorData> actors = new ArrayList<ActorData>();        

    // Initializing actornames arraylist
    String actorname = mMovie.getActorname();
    actornames = Arrays.asList(actorname.split("\\s*,\\s*"));

    // Initializing actorcharacters arraylist
    String actorcharacter = mMovie.getActorcharacter();
    actorcharacters = Arrays.asList(actorcharacter.split("\\s*,\\s*"));

    // Initializing actorphotoFILEpaths arraylist
    String baseFILEpath = "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.miz.mizuu/files/movie-actors/";
    String actorphotourl = mMovie.getActorphotourl();
    actorphotoFILEpaths = Arrays.asList(actorphotourl.split("\\s*,\\s*"));        

    List<ActorData> actors = new ArrayList<ActorData>();
    for (int i = 0; i < actornames.size(); i++) {
    ActorData actorData = new ActorData();
    String name = actornames.get(i);
    actorData.setName(name);
    actors.add(actorData);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < actorcharacters.size(); i++) {
    ActorData actorData = new ActorData();
    String character = actorcharacters.get(i);
    actorData.setCharacter(character);
    actors.add(actorData);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < actorphotoFILEpaths.size(); i++) {
    ActorData actorData = new ActorData();
    String filepath = baseFILEpath + actorphotoFILEpaths.get(i).replaceAll("/", "");
    actorData.setPhotoFILEpath(filepath);
    actors.add(actorData);
    } 
}
```

**POJO class**

```
public class ActorData {
    String name, character, photofilepath;
    public ActorData() {}

    public String getName() {return name;}

    public void setName(String name) {this.name = name;}

    public String getCharacter() {return character;}

    public void setCharacter(String character) {this.character = character;}

    public String getPhotoFILEpath() {return photofilepath;}

    public void setPhotoFILEpath(String photofilepath) {this.photofilepath = photofilepath;}
}
```

Comment: merge the for-cycles(?)

Comment: Thanks but I don't know how to do it, can you help out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## tl;dr

```java
record Actor( String name , String character , Path filePath ) { }

List < String > names = List.of( "Alice" , "Bob" );
List < String > characters = List.of( "Juliet" , "Romeo" );
List < Path > paths = List.of( Paths.get( "filepath1" ) , Paths.get( "filepath2" ) );

if ( ( names.size() + characters.size() + paths.size() ) != ( names.size() * 3 ) )
{
    throw new IllegalStateException( "Input list sizes differ. Message # 075e7165-09d5-4256-8e5e-b5431520b1b4." );
}

List < Actor > actors = new ArrayList <>( names.size() );
for ( int index = 0 ; index < names.size() ; index++ )
{
    actors.add(
            new Actor( names.get( index ) , characters.get( index ) , paths.get( index ) )
    );
}

actors = List.copyOf( actors );
```

## Records

Java 16 and later offers a briefer way to write a class whose main purpose is to communicate data transparently and immutably. You merely declare the name and type of each member field. The compiler implicitly creates the default constructor, getters, `equals` & `hashCode`, and `toString`.  See [JEP 395: Records](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395).

Entire record definition:

```
record Actor( String name , String character , Path filePath ) { }
```

For manipulating paths and files, learn about using Java NIO.2 classes rather than the legacy class. Likely `Path` may be the appropriate class for your needs. See [tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html).

## `List.of`

Make some sample data, written as [unmodifiable lists](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#unmodifiable) using [`List.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#of(E,E,E)).

```java
List < String > names = List.of( "Alice" , "Bob" );
List < String > characters = List.of( "Juliet" , "Romeo" );
List < Path > paths = List.of( Paths.get( "filepath1" ) , Paths.get( "filepath2" ) );
```

## Validate inputs

Verify the size of all the input lists are the same.

```java
if ( ( names.size() + characters.size() + paths.size() ) != ( names.size() * 3 ) )
{
    throw new IllegalStateException( "Input list sizes differ. Message # 075e7165-09d5-4256-8e5e-b5431520b1b4." );
}
```

## Instantiate objects, and collect

And the core logic, assembling elements from each of the three input lists into a new `Actor` object.

```java
List < Actor > actors = new ArrayList <>( names.size() );
for ( int index = 0 ; index < names.size() ; index++ )
{
    actors.add(
            new Actor( names.get( index ) , characters.get( index ) , paths.get( index ) )
    );
}
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "actors = " + actors );
```

When run.

> actors = [Actor[name=Alice, character=Juliet, filePath=filepath1], Actor[name=Bob, character=Romeo, filePath=filepath2]]

Usually best to return an unmodifiable list. Use [`List.copyOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#copyOf(java.util.Collection)).

```
return List.copyOf( actors ) ;
```

Comment: Thanks you so much sir, I tired `List < String > names = List.of( "Alice" , "Bob" );`  but `of` could not be resolved , what could the issue sir, I use java 1.7 ?

Comment: @Steve Use the [latest version of Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html) to see that `List.of` was added to Java 9. And `List.copyOf` was added to Java 10. You will find similar methods in classes in third party libraries such as Google Guava or Eclipse Collections. I don’t know if those are still maintained for Java 7. I suggest you consider moving to a modern LTS version of Java: 8, 11, & 17.

Comment: Right now I'm stuck with 7 so I should use `Arrays.asList` instead, sir it appears that I should make a pojo class specifically for `Path` , right?

Answer (score 0):

I got it done by combining the `for loop`s

```
     List<ActorData> actors = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 0; (i < actornames.size()) && (i < actorcharacters.size()) && (i < actorphotoFILEpaths.size()); i++) {
                    ActorData actorData = new ActorData();
                    String name = actornames.get(i);
                    String character = actorcharacters.get(i);
                    String filepath = baseFILEpath + actorphotoFILEpaths.get(i).replaceAll("/", "");
                    actorData.setName(name);
                    actorData.setCharacter(character);
                    actorData.setPhotoFILEpath(filepath);
                    actors.add(actorData);
                }
```

**output**

```
actors = [
0 = {
     name = "name1",
     character = "character1",
     photofilepath = "photofilepath1"
    },
1 = {
     name = "name2",
     character = "character2",
     photofilepath = "photofilepath2"
    }
]
```

Comment: Before the `for` loop, check that all lists have same size. Then your `for` loop limit can be set to any *one* of the lists’ size.

Comment: @BasilBourque thanks for the input , sir you mean like this `if (actornames.size() == actorcharacters.size() && actorcharacters.size() == actorphotoFILEpaths.size()) {
            List<ActorData> actors = new ArrayList<>();
            .....
        }`

Comment: if they are not equal , data will not be added to `actors`, this is better. Thanks